# Spring boot dependency injection error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring and I tried performing a simple CRUD operation using spring boot but I'm having issues with the dependency injection
Here's my code:

```
package com.teamapt.alm.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by Abayomi on 03/12/2015.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "query", nullable = false)
    private String query;
    @Column(name = "summary", nullable = true)
    private String summary;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
package com.teamapt.alm.repository;

import com.teamapt.alm.model.Report;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ayo on 22-Feb-16.
 */

@Repository
public interface ReportRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<Report, Long> {

    //List<Report> findById(long id);
    List<Report> findByType(String reportType);
}
```

The Controller class:

```
package com.teamapt.alm.controller;


import com.teamapt.alm.model.Report;
import com.teamapt.alm.repository.ReportRepositoryCustom;
import com.teamapt.alm.service.CrudService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Created by Ayo on 22-Feb-16.
 */

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class ReportsController {

    @Autowired
    ReportRepositoryCustom repo;
    //CrudService crudService;

    /*@RequestMapping(value = "/{reportType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String reportTypes(@PathVariable("reportType") String reportType, Model model){
        List<Report> reportList = crudService.findByType(reportType);
        if(reportList!=null) {
            model.addAttribute("", reportList);
        }
        return "reportList";
    }*/

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addReport(Report report){
        repo.save(report);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

The application class:

```
package com.teamapt.alm.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.teamapt.alm.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.teamapt.alm.repository")
@ComponentScan("com.teamapt.alm")
public class AnalyticsCrudApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AnalyticsCrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My error log:

```
2016-02-23 12:19:02.297 ERROR 5644 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.teamapt.alm.repository.ReportRepositoryCustom com.teamapt.alm.controller.ReportsController.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportRepositoryCustom': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property type found for type Report!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.teamapt.alm.config.AnalyticsCrudApplication.main(AnalyticsCrudApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.teamapt.alm.repository.ReportRepositoryCustom com.teamapt.alm.controller.ReportsController.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportRepositoryCustom': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property type found for type Report!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportRepositoryCustom': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property type found for type Report!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property type found for type Report!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

2016-02-23 12:19:02.310  INFO 5644 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-32.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/Downloads/SpringiA4_SourceCode/Chapter_01/ALM%20BUSINESS%20ANALYTICS%20CRUD%20OP/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.30/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.2.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar, file:/C:/Users/Ayo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2015.0/lib/idea_rt.jar]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `JpaRepository<Report, Long>` with `JpaRepository<Report, Integer>`

Comment: @AliDehghani didn't make a difference

Comment: Will application run if you comment `addReport` method in yours controller class?

Answer (score 1):

**Method1**

you should change the signature of method

```
List<Report> findByType(String reportType);
```

into

```
List<Report> findByType(String type);
```

**Method 2**

add `@Query` on your findByType method

```
@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query("select r from Report r where r.type =?1")
List<Report> findByType( String type)
```

Comment: `@Query("select r from Report r where r.type :=type")` is giving me an error at `:` says <expression>, <operator>, AND, GROUP, HAVING, IS, OR expected, got `:`

Comment: i assume you don't have spring data so i will change the query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jparepositroy use crudrepository in the repository class , it might work.